# Help me golf this C program checking for string patterns in a sorted hand of cards

Tags: code-golf, tips, c

I could not think of a better title.

**This is a tips question. I'm asking for tips on golfing my code.**

I recently took part in a code golf competition in C. The competition ended and I lost. The problem is:

> Input a line with a number *n*.
>
> Then input *n* lines, each line contains only a set of cards in descending order, e. g. `X2AAKKKKQT9765433` or `DX22AKKQJTT884443`. Figure out if it contains `DX` **or** four of the same cards in a row.

Obviously, this is a chameleon challenge (finding `DX` is essentially the same as checking the second character if it is `X`, and to check for four of the same cards you only need to check the first and the last card of the quadruplet, because the cards are in descending order.)

In that competition, the input format is strict, and error-terminating is disallowed.

After the competition, we continued to improve on this problem. We've got this so far (98 bytes):

```
char*p,s[99];main(){for(gets(s);gets(p=s);puts(s[1]>87?"Yes":"No"))for(;*p;)s[1]|=*p^p++[3]?0:88;}
```

I'm looking for tips to golf this down further.

Comment: I considered main function recursion to no avail.

Comment: What do the `D` and `X` stand for? I can only guess that one of them represents a joker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**94 bytes**

Instead of increasing `s[1]` when you find a quadruplet, setting it to zero is a bit cheaper. The conditional in `puts` stays the same length:

```c
char*p,s[99];main(){for(gets(s);gets(p=s);puts(s[1]%88?"No":"Yes"))for(;*p;)s[1]*=*p!=p++[3];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z85I7FIq0CnONrSMtY6NzEzT0OzOi2/SCM9taRYo1jTGkwX2AJZBaUgkWjDWFULC3slv3wlK6XI1GIlTU2QcmutAmtNkKSWrVaBom2Btna0cax17f//xlwRRo6O3kAQGGJpbmZqYmzM5RJhZAQUCvQKCbGwMDExAalBEwEA)

[dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) suggested two more improvements:

**93 bytes**

If we can avoid to produce in the first iteration, The initial call to `gets` can be dropped. This is achieved by assuming the first argument to `main` (argc) is 1, which is the case if there are no command line arguments.

```c
char*p,s[99];main(i){for(;gets(p=s);--i&&puts(s[1]%88?"No":"Yes"))for(;*p;)s[1]*=*p!=p++[3];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z85I7FIq0CnONrSMtY6NzEzTyNTszotv0jDOj21pFijwLZY01pXN1NNraAUyC2ONoxVtbCwV/LLV7JSikwtVtLUBCvWKrDWBElq2WoVKNoWaGtHG8da1/7/b8wVYeTo6A0EgSGW5mamJsbGXC4RRkZAoUCvkBALCxMTE5AaNBEA)

**87 bytes**

If you stop the inner for loop as soon a quadruplet is found or the end of input is reached, `*p>0` indicates a quadruplet:

```c
char*p,s[99];main(i){for(;gets(p=s);--i&&puts(s[1]>87|*p?"Yes":"No"))for(;*p++-p[2];);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z85I7FIq0CnONrSMtY6NzEzTyNTszotv0jDOj21pFijwLZY01pXN1NNraAUyC2ONoy1szCv0SqwV4pMLVayUvLLV9LUBKvXKtDW1i2INoq11rSu/f/fmCvCyNHRGwgCQyzNzUxNjI25XCKMjIBCgV4hIRYWJiYmIDVoIgA)

Comment: You can also just enter s[] rather than s[99]. It worked in the tests cases

Comment: @TKirishima For me, I get `error: array size missing in 's'`.

Comment: @TKirishima It does work on TIO, though it starts falling into the realm of undefined behavior. The program may segfault at any point since `s` can technically only store 1 element using that declaration.

Comment: 87 bytes: `char*p,s[99];main(i){for(;gets(p=s);--i&&puts(s[1]>87|*p?"Yes":"No"))for(;*p++-p[2];);}`

Comment: @dingledooper Just using gets once is a nice idea, but I feel like the other part relies on UB. If an input doesn't contain an quadruplet, the second for loop won't terminate at the end of the string. I guess the original code (and mine) suffers from this as well, but only two positions beyond the input. (Or can you assume that there will be zero bytes after the input in `s`, because the way it is defined and all inputs are the same length?)

Comment: @ovs When initialized in the global scope, `s[99]` should be filled with zeros. Even if `p` goes past the "end", I believe there would be enough `0`s afterwards to terminate the loop.